# Connecting to a websocket server from suitescript 2.0

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

Does anyone know if it is possible using suitescript 2.0 to start a websocket connection via a suitelet and listen for messages

Scenario: We have an angular suitelet app that we would like to add more realtime logging to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wouldn't have to start a websocket connection to listen for messages, at least not explicitly.  You could simply set up a suitelet and make it 'Available Without Login' in the deployment.  Then you can POST to the suitelet (using the external URL) with what you want to log and have the suitelet create a custom log record.  For better security, you can use a RESTlet instead, but the authentication requirements can add a lot of additional work and make it difficult to get a minimum viable example running.  I would probably go with a suitelet first, and once working I'd review for any potential security concerns and convert to a RESTlet if there are any.